Proving the symmetry of co-efficients in the complex exponential representation of fourier series
I'm trying to understand why a certain statement is true in the (excellent) book "Lectures on the Fourier Transform and its Applications" by Brad Osgood.
On page 10 there is an argument that says that a function $f(t)$ is real iff the co-efficients $c_n$ in its complex exponential fourier series representation satisfy the symmetry condition $c_{-n} = \overline{c_n}$.
The "if" part of the proof goes: If $f(t)$ is real, then:
$$ f(t) = \sum_{n=-N}^{N} c_ne^{2\pi int} = \overline{\sum_{n=-N}^{N} c_ne^{2\pi int}} = ... = \sum_{n=-N}^{N} \overline c_n e^{-2\pi int} $$
he then finishes with "...and equating like terms gives the relation $c_{-n} = \overline c_n$".

Its not immediately obvious to me so I'm trying to expand this argument. Moving things around a bit in the above equality we have:
$$ \sum_{n=-N}^{N} (c_n - \overline c_{-n})e^{2\pi int} = 0 $$
So writing $a_n = (c_n - \overline c_{-n})$ and $z = e^{2\pi it}$ this is an equation of the form:
$$ \sum_{n=-N}^{N} a_n z^n  = 0$$
with $\|z\| = 1$.
Now this is not simply a case of a polynomial of nth degree being identically zero, since we have negative powers of z. So the argument instead can be perhaps - due to the uniqueness of the laurent series representation of a complex-valued function we have that $a_n = 0$ for all n, since that would be the laurent series coefficients for the zero function?
Is that a valid formal argument? and/or am I missing something simpler?

Suppose $p$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, and $p(x_k) = 0$ for $n+1$ values $x_k$. What can you conclude about the coefficients of $p$?

of course p is identically zero in that case by the fundamental theorem of algebra.. but again note that here we are summing from -N to N so that there are negative powers

I am sure that you can use that hint to prove the desired conclusion :-).

I can say something like: setting $z=0$ we have necessarily $a_0 = 0$, and from there I can multiply the whole shaboodle with $z^n$ to get a standard polynomial equation of degree 2n equalling zero and then use fundamental theorem of algebra.. is that it?? :)

Consider the polynomial $p(z) = z^N\sum_{n=-N}^{N} a_n z^n$.

A Laurent series approach will also suffice, but is overkill perhaps?

Thanks, yep multiplying by z^N is what I came up with in response to your earlier comment as well (I wrote n meant N). Agreed re Laurent being overkill in this case!
